# Add styling to 2nd child of div with known class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, attributes, styling

```
<a href="" class="header-logolink">

    <div>
        <img class="header-logoimage" src="~/images/SummerFling-logo.jpeg" alt="Summer Fling"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h1 class="header-logotext">Summer Fling</h1>
    </div>

</a>
```

How can I add separate styling to the 2 `<div>`'s here without adding classes to the `<div>`'s?

I have tried using:

```
.header-logolink:nth-child(1) {

}
```

But that affects the styling of `<a>` instead of the first `<div>` as seen here.

Comment: `.header-logolink :nth-child(1)` … You need a space (descendant combinator) in the selector between the parent and child elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are selecting the anchor tag with the nth element, you have to select div and then specify the nth element like the below

```
.header-logolink div:nth-child(1) {
  background-color:red;
}

.header-logolink div:nth-child(2) {
  background-color:green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to style the first div child

```
.header-logolink div:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help

```
.swiper-button-prev:after, .swiper-rtl .swiper-button-next:after,.swiper-button-next:after, .swiper-rtl .swiper-button-prev:after {display: none;}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).